# How to use AWS Mobile Hub with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nativescript, aws-mobilehub, nativescript-cli

I searched a lot but never found a way to Integrate and use AWS MobileHub in NativeScript Project. i am very new to NativeScript, so can anybody out there help me please.

In official documentation there is a SDK for React Native found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-react-native-getting-started.html#mobile-hub-react-native-getting-started-configure-aws-amplify)  but i am unable to use that in Native Script.

Comment: If you are looking for storage support, it's implemented in [nativescript-aws-sdk](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-aws-sdk) plugin. If you are looking at other features, you may have to implement it natively by following the iOS / Android documentation.

Comment: thanks @Manoj for your reply i want to access Mobilehub login and nosql database.